# Twilio Javascript : Cannot make auto outbound call when FireFox browser lose focus

Tags: javascript, firefox, twilio

I am using Firefox browser (v71.0, 32bit) to run the web application.

And I would like to setup and make auto call in 20 seconds later once the application loaded (device setup), and lose the focus from the FireFox browser (i.e. Show the windows desktop or open Google Chrome etc...)

I have implemented the code below:

```
console.log("Will make auto call in 20 sec...");
setTimeout(function(){
  makeCall();
}, 20 * 1000);

function makeCall(){
  // get the phone number to connect the call to
  var params = {
    To: MY_DEST_NUM
  };

  console.log('Calling ' + params.To + '...');
  if (device) {
    console.log("Calling debug 1");

    var outgoingConnection = device.connect(params);
    console.log(outgoingConnection);

    //cannot run below codes when browser lose focus
    outgoingConnection.on('ringing', function() {
      log('Ringing...');
      console.log("Calling debug 2");
    });
  }
}
```

However, after 20 seconds, Twilio client will not run the outgoingConnection's ringing event.
And the FireFox browser console log only displayed:

> Will make auto call in 20 sec...
>
> Calling XXXXXXXXXX...
>
> Calling debug 1
>
> {outgoingConnection object}

It hadn't run the following line:

> Calling debug 2

If I focus the browser again (i.e. 30 seconds later), then it can display "Calling debug 2" in the console log and start making outbound call.
Are there any ways that able to let it make auto call when the browser lose focus? Thanks.

Comment: Browsers tend to pause application JavaScript when they are in the background. Does this code work as expected if you the browser retains focus?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code work as expected if the browser retains focus. However, I have no idea why it cannot fire the ringing event, other JavaScript coding can run properly even the FireFox browser lose focus...

Comment: One other thing to try, if you make the connection then draw focus from Firefox does that work? That is, keep Firefox in the foreground until the call starts and then background it. My guess is that maybe [Firefox throttles things unless there is a real time stream open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#Policies_in_place_to_aid_background_page_performance).

Comment: Yes I am now running in this way, but it is quite inconvenience to focus the FireFox browser and switch back to my original working windows for each call ... Do you know any flags (like "chrome://flags" in Chrome) that can modify in FireFox configuration that can bypass this limitation? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. Is there a reason you are switching between browsers to make calls like this?

Comment: Since I have multiple 'tabs' (~10 tabs currently) that would be open the auto-dial web application. Actually they are built with auto-redial feature. So I have to switch to the specific FireFox tab when the calls are going to redial. So I got trouble to handle with those tabs...

Comment: Might it be easier to make your dialler application a browser extension? Or build the dialler so that you can iframe in other pages at the same time?

Comment: Build into iframe is also a good suggestion, I will try it, thanks so much, Phil.